# combining two doctrine2 queries into one

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following query:

```
  $query = $qb->select('DISTINCT s')
              ->from("MainBundle:Shop", 's')
              ->andWhere('SOUNDEX(s.fullname) = SOUNDEX(:shopName)');
  $parameter["shopName"] = $searchquery;
  $query->setParameters($parameter);

  $query = $qb->select('DISTINCT s')
              ->from("MainBundle:Shop", 's')
              ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('s.fullname', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $searchquery . '%')));
```

Is it possible two combine these two query into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second query works, this should work:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

$qb = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT DISTINCT s
    FROM MainBundle:Shop p
    WHERE Soundex(s.fullname) = :soundex(shopname) OR
        ($qb->expr()->like('s.fullname', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $searchquery . '%')))
');
$parameter["shopName"] = $searchquery;
$query->setParameters($parameter);
```

Comment: can you do OR without writing a query?

Comment: I have not checked but I guess so. You can use the operators "AND" and "OR" to concatenate properties so I guess yes.